# Woocommerce: Item B is purchasable if item A added to the cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was trying to modify the WooCommerce Is_Purchasable option so that, item B is purchasable if item A is added to the cart.

I managed to disable add-to-cart button for item B with the code below. But when item A is added to the cart, the page won't load.

Here's the code:

```
function wc_product_is_in_the_cart( $ids ) {
    $cart_ids = array();
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $cart_product = $values['data'];
        $cart_ids[]   = $cart_product->id;
    }
    if ( ! empty( array_intersect( $ids, $cart_ids ) ) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
function wc_product_is_purchasable ( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
        $product_ids = array( '249' );
    if ( ! wc_product_is_in_the_cart( $product_ids ) ) {
       return ($product->id == 2983 ? false : $is_purchasable);
    }
    return $is_purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'wc_product_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
```

I've tried a bunch of ways, but nothing seems working. How should I go on with this?

Comment: Ahyat, Instead of `WC()->cart->get_cart()` in the code of Sark, try to replace it by `WC()->cart->cart_contents` … Please tell me if it works… thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet.

```
function wc_product_is_purchasable ( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    /* List of product ids that must be in the cart 
     * in order to make the particular product purchasable */
    $product_ids = array( '249' );
    // The actual product, on which the purchasable status should be determined
    $concerned_pid = 2983;

    if( $product->id == $concerned_pid ) {
        // make it false
        $is_purchasable = false;
        // get the cart items object
        $cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
        foreach ( $cart_items as $key => $item ) {
            // do your condition
            if( in_array( $item["product_id"], $product_ids ) ) {
                // Eligible product found on the cart 
                $is_purchasable = true;
                break;
            }
        }   
    }

    return $is_purchasable;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'wc_product_is_purchasable', 99, 2 );
```

Comment: The add to cart button is removed but It gives 500 internal error when checkout.

Comment: And here is in the error log: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_cart() on null in functions.php on line 504